Make a class currency convertor for 3 given currencies
I need to implement a currency converter for 3 given currencies + a couple of methods to manage them. Here are requirements:

Implement class Currency and inherited classes Euro, Dollar, and Pound. The course is 1 EUR == 2 USD == 100 GBP

You need to implement the following methods:


course – a classmethod which returns string in the following pattern: {float value} {currency to} for 1 {currency for}
  >>> print(
      f"Euro.course(Pound)   ==> {Euro.course(Pound)}\n"
      f"Dollar.course(Pound) ==> {Dollar.course(Pound)}\n"
      f"Pound.course(Euro)   ==> {Pound.course(Euro)}\n"
  )
  Euro.course(Pound)   ==> 100.0 GBP for 1 EUR
  Dollar.course(Pound) ==> 50.0 GBP for 1 USD
  Pound.course(Euro)   ==> 0.01 EUR for 1 GBP

to_currency – this method transforms the currency from one currency to another. The method should return an instance of a required currency.
  >>> e = Euro(100)
  >>> r = Pound(100)
  >>> d = Dollar(200)

  >>> print(
      f"e = {e}\n"
      f"e.to_currency(Dollar) = {e.to_currency(Dollar)}\n"
      f"e.to_currency(Pound) = {e.to_currency(Pound)}\n"
      f"e.to_currency(Euro)   = {e.to_currency(Euro)}\n"
  )
  e = 100 EUR
  e.to_currency(Dollar) = 200.0 USD  # Dollar instance printed
  e.to_currency(Pound) = 10000.0 GBP  # Pound instance printed
  e.to_currency(Euro)   = 100.0 EUR  # Euro instance printed

  >>> print(
      f"r = {r}\n"
      f"r.to_currency(Dollar) = {r.to_currency(Dollar)}\n"
      f"r.to_currency(Euro)   = {r.to_currency(Euro)}\n"
      f"r.to_currency(Pound) = {r.to_currency(Pound)}\n"
  )
  r = 100 GBP
  r.to_currency(Dollar) = 2.0 USD  # Dollar instance printed
  r.to_currency(Euro)   = 1.0 EUR  # Euro instance printed
  r.to_currency(Pound) = 100.0 GBP  # Pound instance printed

+ - returns an instance of a new value
  >>> e = Euro(100)
  >>> r = Pound(100)
  >>> d = Dollar(200)
  >>> print(
  f"e + r  =>  {e + r}\n"
  f"r + d  =>  {r + d}\n"
  f"d + e  =>  {d + e}\n"
  )
  e + r  =>  101.0 EUR  # Euro instance printed
  r + d  =>  10100.0 GBP  # Pound instance printed
  d + e  =>  400.0 USD  # Dollar instance printed

other comparison methods: > < ==
Here is my code. I wrote to_currency method and overwritten the add one. Please help me with other comparisons and a course one. Thanks!
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Type


class Currency:
    """
    1 EUR = 2 USD = 100 GBP

    1 EUR = 2 USD    ;  1 EUR = 100 GBP
    1 USD = 0.5 EUR  ;  1 USD = 50 GBP
    1 GBP = 0.02 USD ;  1 GBP = 0.01 EUR
    """

    def __init__(self, value: float):
        self.value = value

    @classmethod
    def course(cls, other_cls: Type[Currency]) -> str:
        pass

    def to_currency(self, other_cls: Type[Currency]):
        pass


class Euro(Currency):

    def __init__(self, value: float):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.value = value

    def to_currency(self, other_cls: Type[Currency]):
        if other_cls == Dollar:
            result = float(self.value * 2)
            return result
        elif other_cls == Pound:
            result = float(self.value * 100)
            return result
        elif other_cls == Euro:
            result = float(self.value)
            return result

    def __add__(self, other):
        if other == r:
            return self.value + 1
        elif other == d:
            return self.value + 50

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if other == r:
            return False
        elif other == d:
            return False

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.value > other

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other == r:
            return self.value == r


class Dollar(Currency):

    def __init__(self, value: float):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.value = value

    def to_currency(self, other_cls: Type[Currency]):
        if other_cls == Dollar:
            result = float(self.value)
            return result
        elif other_cls == Pound:
            result = float(self.value * 50)
            return result
        elif other_cls == Euro:
            result = float(self.value * 0.5)
            return result

    def __add__(self, other):
        if other == r:
            return self.value + 2
        elif other == e:
            return self.value + 200


class Pound(Currency):
    def __init__(self, value: float):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.value = value

    def to_currency(self, other_cls: Type[Currency]):
        if other_cls == Dollar:
            result = float(self.value * 0.02)
            return result
        elif other_cls == Pound:
            result = float(self.value)
            return result
        elif other_cls == Euro:
            result = float(self.value * 0.01)
            return result

    def __add__(self, other):
        if other == e:
            return self.value + 20000
        elif other == d:
            return self.value + 10000


Sorry, no, but, you first. Please update your question with possible sample implementations or suggestions about how to go about it.

@quamrana well, I tried comparison methods but they don't work. Look at the code
